# $\int_0^1 x^{n-1} \left(\ln \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)\right)^ndx$ and $\int_0^1 x^{n-1} \ln \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)dx < \infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

How can I prove that  that $$\int_0^1 x^{n-1} \left(\ln \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)\right)^ndx < \infty$$ and $$\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{x \ln^n\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)}dx < \infty,$$ 
where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \ge 1$?

**Context.**

- These integrals come up in an unrelated problem, which is not relevant.
- I'm aware of the integrability conditions for $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^\alpha}dx$, but I'm unsure as to how to handle the logarithm.

Comment: If this is homework, what have you tried? If not, where did you encounter this problem? [Context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) is important.

Comment: Please tell us what $n$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Using the transformation $x \mapsto 1/x$, it is equivalent to consider the integrals $$\int^\infty_{1}\frac{\log(\log(1+x))^n}{x^{n-1}}\frac{dx}{x^2} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \int^\infty_1 \frac{x}{\log(1+x)^n} \frac{dx}{x^2}.$$ Since $\log(x) \lesssim x^\epsilon$ (and thus  $\log(x)^n \lesssim x^\epsilon$) for any $\epsilon > 0$ as $x \to \infty$, we see that the first integral converges so long as $$\int^\infty_{1} \frac{1}{x^{n+1-\epsilon}} dx$$ converges. Since we can choose epsilon arbitrarily small, we can make this converge so long as $n+1 > 1$ or $\boxed{n > 0}$.

For the second we use that $\log(1+x) \ge \log(x)$ and so (since the only difficulty is behavior at $\infty$), the second converges so long as $$\int^\infty_{M} \frac{1}{x\log(x)^n} dx$$ for some arbitrary large $M$.  Using $u = \log(x)$, we see this is equivalent to congervence of $$\int^\infty_{\log(M)}\frac{du}{u^n} $$ which converges when $\boxed{n > 1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. But note that the first integral is actually $\int_0^1 x^{n-1} \left(\ln \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)\right)^ndx$. Previously I had a typo in the question.

Comment: That $n$ doesn't matter so the answer remains the same. I will edit.

Comment: Why $\log(x) \lesssim x^\epsilon \implies \log(\log(1+x))^n \lesssim x^\epsilon?$

Comment: Just use the bound recursively. If $\log(x) \lesssim x^\epsilon$, then $$\log(\log(x)) \lesssim \log(x^\epsilon) = \epsilon \log(x) \sim \log(x) \lesssim x^\epsilon$$ now when you raise both sides to the power $n$ you change the power on the right, but since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, you can account for this by simply switching $\epsilon$ for $\epsilon / n$.